# ConTeXt mkiv: Footnote inside tabulation

Tags: tables, footnotes, context, context-mkiv

I need to include a `\footnote` inside a `tabulation` environment. I adapted the example from ConTeXt wiki, but at compiling the content between `\starttabulatehead` and `\stoptabulatehead` doesn't show up and the content appears aligned to the left:

```
\starttext
\placetable[here]{Tabla.}
{\startlocalfootnotes\placelegend
{\starttabulatehead
\NC A \NC B \SR
\stoptabulatehead}
{\starttabulate[|l|l|]
\NC C\footnote{Nota al pie.} \NC D \NR
\stoptabulate}
{\placelocalfootnotes}
\stoplocalfootnotes}
\stoptext
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: The syntax of `\placelegend` has changed. See my comment to Marco's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
\starttext

\startplacetable [title=Tabla]
  \startlocalfootnotes

    \starttabulatehead
      \NC A \NC B \SR
    \stoptabulatehead

    \starttabulate[|l|l|]
      \NC C \footnote{Nota al pie.} \NC D \NR
    \stoptabulate

    \placelocalfootnotes
  \stoplocalfootnotes
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

To prevent the table from floating add the `location=here` option.
If you want the table to be centred use `\midaligned`:

```
\startplacetable [title=Tabla, location=here]
  \startlocalfootnotes

    \starttabulatehead
      \NC A \NC B \SR
    \stoptabulatehead

    \midaligned{\vbox{%
      \starttabulate[|l|l|]
        \NC C \footnote{Nota al pie.} \NC D \NR
      \stoptabulate}}

    \midaligned{\placelocalfootnotes}
  \stoplocalfootnotes
\stopplacetable
```

[image: result]

**Edit:**

As Aditya mentioned in the comment, a better solution than the
`\midaligned` is to use the new legend mechanism. Here an example:

```
\startplacetable [title=Tabla]
  \startlocalfootnotes

    \starttabulatehead
      \NC A \NC B \SR
    \stoptabulatehead

    \startplacelegend [location=top] %% default is bottom
      \startcontent
        \vbox\bgroup
          \starttabulate[|l|l|]
            \NC C \footnote{Nota al pie.} \NC D \NR
          \stoptabulate
        \egroup
      \stopcontent
      \startcaption
        \placelocalfootnotes
      \stopcaption
    \stopplacelegend

  \stoplocalfootnotes
\stopplacetable
```

Comment: You can also use `\startplacelegend[location={...}] \startcontent <table> \stopcontent \startcaption \placelocalfootnote \stopcontent \stoplegend` instead of `\midaligned{...}`. This gives you more structure (important when you think in terms of exporting to other formats), and also gives a easier way to control the location of the notes).

Comment: Semantically that would be a better solution, indeed. But `\placelegend` is very brittle, it fails if you directly place the tabulate inside the content pair, you need to put the content in a box. Or a newline after `\placelegend` fails as well as `\placelegend[location=left]`.

Comment: I'd call the current behavior (need to include the material in a vbox) as an implementation bug.